# Microsoft Project releationship VBA code

Tags: vba, tfs, ms-project

I am doing a working semester right now, with the course of study bachelor of business computing. I am not an expert in coding (think got some OK basics) nor I am a 100% fluent in English as my 2nd language so be a bit gentle on mistakes or "bumpy" formulations.

**My Task:**

I am working on a template, which will be handed to the company's project managers to make it easier for them to "load up" backlogs into TFS and assign tasks via MS Project.
The template itself is kinda finished right now, but I have one more problem to tackle.

**Automatizing the "Create Relationship Process" between Backlog Items and     Tasks**

TFS cant create "Parent-Child-Relationships" with the "Parent Backlog" not published yet. 
This means, I have to find a way (thinking of a macro/VBA) to create the relationships AND to publish some items of MS Project **first**, then creating the relationship and publish the rest.

```
Macro Start --> publish all backlogs --> creating relationships --> publish relations + tasks --> Macro End
```

The tricky part for me is, that it has to be as simple and intuitive as possible to use.

I hope I managed to impress myself at least a little bit understandable and someone has a little help for me.

I used Google and the Stackoverflow Search, but didn't get a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was my own bad. 
I only tried to for testcases the first 5-10 Tasks/Backlogs. But for MS Project + Tfs you need to fix all "publish errors" to get the connections to work @tfs.

Greetings Declade

Answer (score 0):

There is out of the box integration between TFS and both Excel and MS Project. If you install Team Explorer you will get a "Team" tab in both products.

Comment: i know that of course :) . but my problem is that iam trying to create a universal template. That means: someone copys my template for a new Project. Will the relations still work?